# Rest API .NET how to load/(not)load nested entities on demand?

Tags: c#, api, entity-framework, automapper

I have a .NET Rest API with a controller. This controller is answering requests for an entity `School`.
My database has many `School`s and each `School` has many `Student`s.

Sometimes I want this query to return all `School`s with their `Student`s, but sometimes I want to return only the list of `School`s.

I have tried something: I have set a boolean param on the query `includeStudents` that should modify the internal SQL query to join with Students table, by using `Include` method from Entity Framework.

```
public class SchoolsController:ApiController
    {
        [System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<SchoolsDTO> Index(int? id = null, bool? includeStudents=null)
        {
            using (MyDatabase db = new MyDatabase())
            {
                string includeString = "";
                if(includeStudents.HasValue && includeStudents.Value)
                {
                    includeString = ".Students";
                }
                var schools = db.Schools.Include(includeString).AsQueryable();
                if (id.HasValue)
                {
                    schools = schools.Where(x => x.Id == id);
                }
               
                return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<SchoolsDTO>>(schools.ToList());
            }
        }
    }
```

But it is always resolving and serializing to JSON the `Student`s for all schools, no matter if I use `Include` or not.

Edit: I am using AutoMapper to work with DTOs, but DTOs of these objects are just identical copies of original EF objects.

How can I solve this?

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html

Answer (score -1):

try this code

```
      var schools = db.Schools.Where(x => id==0 || x.Id == id ).AsQueryable();

       if(includeStudents != null && includeStudents)
       {
          schools = schools.Include(s=> s.Students);
        } else schools.Students=null;
             
      return AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<List<SchoolsDTO>>(schools.ToList());
```

Comment: somehow it is still loading all nested relationship

Comment: @E.Williams Yes, it will if you  load the realationships before and after this will try load again without.  I updated my answer.